# Any idea about how to make this table nicer?

Tags: tables

My current table is too tight, and the caption is too long or too big. Any idea about how to make this table nicer?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!]
    \centering 
    \caption{Seven semantic models and their symbols representation}
    \label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}
    \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}<{\centering}p{5cm}<{\centering}}
    \toprule
     \textbf{Models} & \textbf{Symbol representation} \\
     \hline
    Assets & AS \\
    \hline
    Task & T \\
    \hline
    Product & PRT \\
    \hline
    Reconfiguration & RS \\
    \hline
    Process & PRS \\
    \hline
    Capability & CAB \\
    \hline
    Capacity   & CAP \\    
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace the first `\hline` by `\midrule` and drop the other `\hline`'s (they don't help with readability. I'd also left align, not center.

Comment: the fact that `p{4cm}<{\centering}` centres at all is by accident not design and requires no blank lines in the input. `>{\centering}p{4cm}` would be more usual, but I would  not center here

Answer (score 2):

Is this helpful for you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!]
    \centering 
    \caption{Seven semantic models and their symbols representation}
    \label{table:semantic models of OCCR model}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lc@{}}
    \toprule
     \textbf{Models} & \textbf{Symbol representation} \\
\midrule
    Assets & AS \\
    Task & T \\
    Product & PRT \\
    Reconfiguration & RS \\
    Process & PRS \\
    Capability & CAB \\
    Capacity   & CAP \\    
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]